# Why does Celery have different Python Path in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am setting up celery with Flask app. My app folder structure is as follows:

[image]

`app.py` in `sonip_api/sonip` is the entry point:

```
app = factory.flask

def main():
    app.run(debug=settings.FLASK_DEBUG)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am following  [this example](https://github.com/matthieugouel/python-flask-celery-example) to have `flask` and `celery` app declared in a `factory.py` under `sonip_api/sonip/api`.

The actual celery task function is defined in `sonip_api/sonip/api/resources/main.py` along with these endpoints.

I was able to run `python sonip/app.py` under directory `sonip_api`. However, I got error running `celery -A  sonip.api.celery worker` in the same directory:

```
File "C:\Users\dxx\WorkSpace\sonip_api\sonip\api\factory.py", line 4, in <module>
    import settings
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'
```

It can be fixed by adding `sonip` in front of `settings` for the import. But then Flask app won't run. It seems like a path issue, I don't understand why celery's pythonpath is different than flask's. I am sure if I move everything out of `sonip` to the root directory, both Flask and celery commands would work. But I don't want my app under the same level as `env` etc.

Comment: Can't see your `settings.py` from your project structure. Did have create it anywhere?

Comment: @FrankAK `settings.py` is under `sonip`, same level as `app.py`. You can see it at the bottom of my screenshot

Comment: But your just import at `\api\factory.py`, do not at the same directory with your `settings.py`

Comment: @FrankAK But why does Flask work just fine importing settings like the way it is. It seems like Flask treat `sonip` as the root path for all the module imports.